# Create new column based on strings within the same list in R

Tags: r, json, string, list, data.table

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find something similar after thirty minutes of searching though.

dput:

```
structure(list(i = c("KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", 
"KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "KHH", 
"KHH", "KHH", "KHH", "YYR", "YYR", "YYR", "YYR", "YYR", "YYR", 
"YYR", "YYR"), n = c("Changzhi", "Chaochou", "Chaozhou", "Checheng", 
"Donggang", "Fangliao", "Fangshan", "Fengshan", "Gaoshu", "Hengchun Old Town", 
"Jiuru", "Linbian", "Liuqiu", "Manzhou", "Pingtung", "Tungkang", 
"Wanluan", "Yanpu", "Cartwright", "Happy Valley - Goose Bay", 
"Hopedale", "Makkovik", "Nain", "Natuashish", "Postville", "Rigolet"
), c = c("Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", 
"Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", 
"Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), 
    C = c("TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", 
    "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "TW", "CA", 
    "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA"), r = c("Eastern Asia", 
    "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", 
    "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", 
    "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", 
    "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", 
    "Eastern Asia", "Northern America", "Northern America", "Northern America", 
    "Northern America", "Northern America", "Northern America", 
    "Northern America", "Northern America"), L = c(120.576, 120.539, 
    120.533, 120.717, 120.482, 120.593, 120.657, 120.35, 120.625, 
    120.744, 120.487, 120.488, 120.383, 120.848, 120.488, 120.449, 
    120.625, 120.574, -57.042, -60.377, -60.229, -59.186, -61.68, 
    -61.184, -59.785, -58.458), F = c(22.701, 22.55, 22.552, 
    22.06, 22.459, 22.368, 22.249, 22.633, 22.737, 22.005, 22.725, 
    22.428, 22.352, 21.991, 22.672, 22.465, 22.612, 22.76, 53.683, 
    53.31, 55.448, 55.077, 56.549, 55.914, 54.91, 54.18)), sorted = "i", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

dput wasn't working with the list/data.table so I put it up as a dataframe. If it would help you to put it into a list then you can run `split(df[, -1],df$i)`

I would like to take the name of each row within each list and put it into a new list within each row.

I have a large list which looks like this:

```
    i                        n      c  C                r       L      F
1 YYR               Cartwright Canada CA Northern America -57.042 53.683
2 YYR Happy Valley - Goose Bay Canada CA Northern America -60.377 53.310
3 YYR                 Hopedale Canada CA Northern America -60.229 55.448
4 YYR                 Makkovik Canada CA Northern America -59.186 55.077
5 YYR                     Nain Canada CA Northern America -61.680 56.549   <-- this row is used in the example
6 YYR               Natuashish Canada CA Northern America -61.184 55.914
...
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

**df$YYR**

```
             n      c  C                r       L      F x
1:  Cartwright Canada CA Northern America -59.785 54.910 list()
...
```

**df$YYR["n"][5,]**

```
[1] "Nain"
...
```

**df$YYR[["x"]][5]**     <-- this is the needed structure

```
[[5]]
                         d n      index
1                      YYR Nain   0
2               Cartwright Nain   1
3 Happy Valley - Goose Bay Nain   2
4                 Hopedale Nain   3
5                 Makkovik Nain   4
6               Natuashish Nain   6

...
```

**toJSON(df$YYR["x"][5,])**     <-- hopefully this makes sense because it is confusing me also

```
[
  {
    "d": "YYR",
    "n": "Nain",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "d": "Cartwright",
    "n": "Nain",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "d": "Happy Valley - Goose Bay",
    "n": "Nain",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "d": "Hopedale",
    "n": "Nain",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "d": "Makkovik",
    "n": "Nain",
    "index": 4
  },
...
]
```

similar to expand.grid or cartesian join within each list element but also including a reference to the parent list element as the 0 index value

Comment: your `dput` is giving an error. `Error: unexpected '<' in:
"",0,0,0,", ",0,1,0,")), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .intern"`

Comment: @RonakShah maybe it's fixed now?

Comment: @RonakShah ok so dput doesn't work with data.table. That's why the dput wasn't working

Comment: @jaksco I don't understand what the relation of your desired output is to your sample input. Can you please explain?

Comment: @eddi I've simplified the examples in the output.

Comment: I discovered what I'm looking for is expand.grid but instead of one list I'm looking for something that puts the ones which match the row name into the nested list for that row. As well as the list element at index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you want, but this will produce the example results:

```
res = df[, .(d = c(i, n), idx = 0:.N), by = i]
res[res[idx > 0], on = .(i), allow = T, .(d, n = i.d, idx)][d != n]
#              d        n idx
#  1:        KHH Changzhi   0
#  2:   Chaochou Changzhi   2
#  3:   Chaozhou Changzhi   3
#  4:   Checheng Changzhi   4
#  5:   Donggang Changzhi   5
# ---                        
#384:   Hopedale  Rigolet   3
#385:   Makkovik  Rigolet   4
#386:       Nain  Rigolet   5
#387: Natuashish  Rigolet   6
#388:  Postville  Rigolet   7
```

Comment: this is perfect!! how do I run this as a function on a list? (lapply?) I was able to run this for list$KHH by doing res = with(list, KHH[, .(d = c(i, n), idx = 0:.N), by = i]) (and then the second part). Is there a way to run this so that it will stick the output of both commands within a nested list on the same row, list$KHH ? I want this output to appear if I type something like list$KHH[,c("res")] or another list element